# Accessing my Object properties from javascript and Using MVC razor Url.Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am mixing Javascript and Razor code to redirect to a page sending a couple params.Heres my code that I tried.

```
function insertSuccess(data) {
       $('#NewCategoryGroup').dialog('close');
       var  myId = data.Object.GroupCatId;
       var  myName = data.Object.ItemCategoryGroup;
        window.location.replace("@Url.Action("CatGroupDetails","TaxRules",new { id = myId, name = myName })");
    }
```

I can replace `Id = 1` and `name = "test"` and it works. But when I try to use variables it wont let me. Do I have to write my URL the old way --  "http://www.someweb.com/5?Name=test".
Thanks for the help.

Comment: _"it wont let me"_ What does that mean? What does it do instead of what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your code above myId and myName are javascript variables, but you are trying to use them under the C-Sharp scope. Url.Action is a C# function here.

Comment: So is my only option is to write it like this???:  window.location.replace("/TaxRules/CatGroupDetails/" + myId + "?name=" + myName);

Comment: You can still use Url.Action and have placeholders in the original url. Store that in a javascript variable. And in the next line, replace those placeholders with your id and name values

Comment: var url = "@Url.Action("CatGroupDetails","TaxRules",new { id = "{0}", name = "{1}" })";